# MySQL Query Frequency of Zip Codes per Offices

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, frequency

I am trying to write a MySQL query to see which zip codes come up the most frequently for our customers and need help in completing it. The **office** field at the end of my select statement can be anyway from 1 to 10 possibilities per zip code.

How would I fix this query to get me the most frequent zip codes and which out of the 10 possible offices happen to have a location in that zip code?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(zip_code, 1, 5) AS zip, 
COUNT(*) AS freq, office
FROM customer_billing 
WHERE status != 'deleted'
GROUP BY zip
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Sample output for what I am looking for:

```
zip     freq     office
----    ----     ----
92101    450     office_A, office_B
02124    300     office_A, office_C, office_D
07713    110     office_B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` along with `DISTINCT`.  Using `DISTINCT` is necessary because a given office may occur multiple times for a given zip code.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(zip_code, 1, 5), COUNT(*) AS freq,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT office ORDER BY office DESC SEPARATOR ',')
FROM customer_billing
WHERE status != 'deleted'
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(zip_code, 1, 5)
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
>   values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.
>   The full syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(zip_code, 1, 5) AS zip, 
COUNT(*) AS freq, GROUP_CONCAT(office)
FROM customer_billing 
WHERE status != 'deleted'
GROUP BY zip
ORDER BY freq DESC
```